# kpr() in my form validation and submit function is not being called

Tags: 7, forms, debugging

In my form validation and submit functions, `kpr()` is not being called. Is there a better way to check that I'm in those functions? If `kpr()` isn't ideal to output my `$form_state` array, then what is ideal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything that is output with `drupal_set_message()` (the function that `kpr()` uses to output the message) could not be visible from the browser if code redirects the user to another page after `drupal_set_message()` is called and before the page is rendered. After a form is submitted, the users are redirected to a page whose URL is set in `$form_state['redirect']` or `$_GET['destination']`; the latter takes the precedence over the former.
To avoid the users are redirected after the form is submitted, you can:

- Set `$form_state['rebuild']` to `TRUE`
- Set `$form_state['redirect']` to `FALSE`

Setting `$form_state['no_redirect']` to `TRUE` would have the same effect, but form builder functions, form validation handlers, and form submission handlers should never set `$form_state['no_redirect']`.

A preferred method would be calling [watchdog()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7). If you have the Database Logging module enable, then the message output from the module will be visible in admin/reports/dblog.

For debugging messages, you can call `watchdog()` passing `WATCHDOG_DEBUG` as value for the `$severity` parameter.

#### References

- [drupal_redirect_form()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7)

Comment: I set form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE, and I was able to get kpr() output.

Comment: I expanded the answer to show other ways to avoid users are redirected after form submission.