# How to prevent the form from redirection after submission in order to see the kpr() results?

Tags: forms

I installed [Basic Cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module and I needed to completely modify its submission handler. So I used the following code:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'order_node_form'){
        $form['#submit'] = array("my_form_order_submit_handler");
    }
}
```

and It works perfectly. The `order_node_form` form has some values in its inputs and I need to get them. I don't know how to get the values from the `$form` variable so I need to `kpr` this variable. This is the `my_form_order_submit_handler` function:

```
function my_form_order_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
    kpr(1);
}
```

The problem is it doesn't `kpr` the `1` and is redirected to some where else. In the question [kpr() in my form validation and submit function is not being called](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82319/kpr-in-my-form-validation-and-submit-function-is-not-being-called?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) it has been suggested to add the following codes in form alter function and tried this code:

```
function THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'order_node_form'){
        $form['#submit'] = array("my_form_order_submit_handler");
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
        $form_state['no_redirect'] = TRUE;
        $form_state['redirect'] = FALSE;
    }
}
```

But it is still redirected and I can't see the `kpr(1)` result in the submission function. How can I prevent the page being redirected to some where else after the `my_form_order_submit_handler` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `die()` after `kpr()`.

Comment: OR `exit;` after kpr()

Comment: Or learn to use a debugger...